# How do I connect the PiCamera to the Raspberry Pi 5?

Tags: picamera

So I just got one of the [Raspberry Pi Camera Module 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ER2SKFS). On the [website](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera/2), it says that you install it by plugging it into one of the camera ports on the board (the RPI5 has two). On the schema, the ribbon cable is narrower than the port, and fits nicely inside the plastic clip:

[image: Picture showing how to plug the ribbon cable, from RaspberryPi's official website]

Here's my problem. My ribbon cable isn't narrower than the port, it's exactly as long. As a result, I can't seem to be able to plug it in:

[image: Picture of my ribbon cable]

Note that the ribbon is as wide as the white part, and covers both sides of the black clip. I broke the clip on the other port while trying to insert the ribbon, but as you can see, it also extends past the metallic pins in the white part.

Is there something I'm not getting? Am I supposed to trim the sides of the ribbon? Or did I get the wrong module somehow?

Comment: the flex cable has more contacts than the connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buy the camera adapter cable for the Pi5.

https://thepihut.com/products/camera-adapter-cable-for-raspberry-pi-5

Comment: Aha! You would have thought this would be mentioned on the official webpage. Thanks for info.

Comment: @Timst  If you actually read the Pi5 documentation it would be clear.

Comment: I'm sure. But I would have thought it would be mentioned on the PiCamera doc as well, given that this is a significant breaking change (and it also impacts Pi Zero/Zero 2Ws as well).